# "of class NSURL autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking" Help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, autorelease

```
-(void)setIT:(customOfferCell *)curr {
    NSAutoreleasePool *imagePool = [ [ NSAutoreleasePool alloc ] init ];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]autorelease];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
    curr.offerImage.image = [[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]autorelease];
    [imagePool drain];
}
```

Hi I had the title error and the program ran fine, but the number of leaks concerned me, I looked into what was causing it and because this method is called on a new thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(setIT:) toTarget:self withObject:cell];
```

I need to create an autorelease pool and autorelease the objects. The above method is called to load an image onto my custom UITableViewCell. When I run this I get weird errors on delegates that aren't even running. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your objects with factory methods that return autorelease values, and then you are autoreleasing them!  That should lead to an over-release problem, not a leak, though.

Comment: Thanks, once I remove the code the application runs perfectly but the console display this:
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5a90570 of class NSURL autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 20:47:33.026 CorkSSG[276:13c07] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xfde660 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 20:47:33.028 CorkSSG[276:13c07] ***

Comment: @richard what code did you remove?  The only code you should remove are the explicit calls to `autorelease`.

Comment: Oh I removed the NSAutoReleasePool too, I've now re-added it and it now seems to be running ok!

Comment: methods like `-URLWithString:` return autorelease values, so you need a pool in place.  You should probably read the memory management guide.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I get that now! Thanks for the quick reply